# Simple MIDI library that gives me a list of notes

Tags: vb.net, midi

I'd like to create a little program that would just take a MIDI file and give me a list of notes (like G1, F4, D6...) which I could use further in another program... But I can't find any library that does that, generally they just play the sound... Do you know how I could achieve doing that ?

Thank you

Comment: http://www.midi.org/techspecs/index.php

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to print out the notes in a MIDI file look at [MuseScore](http://musescore.org/).  It's a stand-alone program. MuseScore can import and export MIDI and MusicXML files.  MIDI files are a binary format, which is harder to parse for the information you want.  MuseScore can convert MIDI files to MusicXML files, which should be easier to parse.

Have you looked at [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/)?  It is a .NET project that works with MIDI files.  You can check out its source code on Codeplex.

Answer (score 2):

[MIDI.NET](http://midinet.codeplex.com/) is a midi library that gives you basic functionality including reading a midi file - there is a sample that demonstrates that. It also has a class -MidiNoteName- that can convert a note number to and from a note name (for instance C4 or G2 etc.)